# QGIS Plugin : failing to change plugin language with qm files

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins, internationalization

I am currently having an issue when trying to associate 3 different languages (French, English and Spanish) to my plugin. The original language is French, and I want to swap to English or Spanish according to the preferences options.

I found very few examples to study on the internet.

I followed the "Translation" section of this tutorial : [Developing python plugins](https://docs.qgis.org/2.18/bg/docs/pyqgis_developer_cookbook/plugins.html#translation) and applied it to one tab of my project :

- I made the .pro file in folder i18n
- I generated the ts files, both for English and Spanish
- In Qt Linguist, I set the translations for all my labels and buttons
- I used the lreleased.exe in the Qt Linguist folder to create the qm files.

Then I went into QGIS -> Settings -> Options and I set "User Interface translation" to "American English" and later to "Espanol de Espana". I closed QGIS and opened it again.

And yet, my plugin is still in French.

Can someone tell me why? Should I add something new in my resources.qrc file? Or in a python file?

NB :

- I did not change anything in my python and ui files.
- To make sure, I even turned off my computer. The plugin is still in French.

In case it would be useful, here are my files.

Pro file :

```
FORMS = ../mon_super_calculateur_dialog_base.ui
SOURCES = ../mon_super_calculateur_dialog.py ../mon_super_calculateur.py
TRANSLATIONS = mon_super_calculateur_en.ts mon_super_calculateur_es.ts
```

English ts file :

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE TS>
<TS version="2.1" language="en" sourcelanguage="fr">
<context>
    <name>MonSuperCalculateur</name>
    <message>
        <location filename="../mon_super_calculateur.py" line="177"/>
        <source>&amp;Mon Super Calculateur</source>
        <translation>&amp;My Fabulous Calculator</translation>
    </message>
    <message>
        <location filename="../mon_super_calculateur.py" line="164"/>
        <source>Calculer</source>
        <translation>Compute</translation>
    </message>
</context>
<context>
    <name>MonSuperCalculateurDialogBase</name>
    <message>
        <location filename="../mon_super_calculateur_dialog_base.ui" line="14"/>
        <source>Mon Super Calculateur</source>
        <translation>My Fabulous Calculator</translation>
    </message>
    <message>
        <location filename="../mon_super_calculateur_dialog_base.ui" line="165"/>
        <source>Sommer</source>
        <translation>Sum</translation>
    </message>
    <message>
        <location filename="../mon_super_calculateur_dialog_base.ui" line="32"/>
        <source>Afficher &quot;Vous Ãªtes sur l&apos;onglet nÂ°1 : vous pouvez sommer&quot;</source>
        <translation>Display : You are on tab n°1 : You can sum</translation>
    </message>
    <message>
        <location filename="../mon_super_calculateur_dialog_base.ui" line="256"/>
        <source>+</source>
        <translation>+</translation>
    </message>
    <message>
        <location filename="../mon_super_calculateur_dialog_base.ui" line="292"/>
        <source>=</source>
        <translation>+</translation>
    </message>
    <message>
        <location filename="../mon_super_calculateur_dialog_base.ui" line="312"/>
        <source>Résultat</source>
        <translation>Result</translation>
    </message>
    <message>
        <location filename="../mon_super_calculateur_dialog_base.ui" line="185"/>
        <source>Aller plus loin</source>
        <translation>Go further</translation>
    </message>
    <message>
        <location filename="../mon_super_calculateur_dialog_base.ui" line="336"/>
        <source>Multiplier</source>
        <translation>Multiply</translation>
    </message>
    <message>
        <location filename="../mon_super_calculateur_dialog_base.ui" line="203"/>
        <source>Afficher &quot;Vous Ãªtes sur l&apos;onglet nÂ°2 : vous pouvez multiplier&quot;</source>
        <translation>Display : You are on tab n°2 : you can multiply</translation>
    </message>
    <message>
        <location filename="../mon_super_calculateur_dialog_base.ui" line="377"/>
        <source>Langue</source>
        <translation>Language</translation>
    </message>
</context>
</TS>
```

Resources.qrc file :

```xml
<RCC>
    <qresource prefix="/plugins/mon_super_calculateur" >
        <file>icon.png</file>
    </qresource>
</RCC>
```

mon_super_calculateur.py file :

```
from qgis.PyQt.QtCore import QSettings, QTranslator, QCoreApplication
from qgis.PyQt.QtGui import QIcon
from qgis.PyQt.QtWidgets import QAction
from .resources import *
from .mon_super_calculateur_dialog import MonSuperCalculateurDialog
import os.path


class MonSuperCalculateur:
    def __init__(self, iface):
        # Save reference to the QGIS interface
        self.iface = iface
        # initialize plugin directory
        self.plugin_dir = os.path.dirname(__file__)
        # initialize locale
        locale = QSettings().value('locale/userLocale')[0:2]
        locale_path = os.path.join(
            self.plugin_dir,
            'i18n',
            'MonSuperCalculateur_{}.qm'.format(locale))

        if os.path.exists(locale_path):
            self.translator = QTranslator()
            self.translator.load(locale_path)
            QCoreApplication.installTranslator(self.translator)

        # Declare instance attributes
        self.actions = []
        self.menu = self.tr(u'&Mon Super Calculateur')
        self.first_start = None

    # noinspection PyMethodMayBeStatic
    def tr(self, message):
        return QCoreApplication.translate('MonSuperCalculateur', message)

    def add_action(
        self,
        icon_path,
        text,
        callback,
        enabled_flag=True,
        add_to_menu=True,
        add_to_toolbar=True,
        status_tip=None,
        whats_this=None,
        parent=None):

        icon = QIcon(icon_path)
        action = QAction(icon, text, parent)
        action.triggered.connect(callback)
        action.setEnabled(enabled_flag)

        if status_tip is not None:
            action.setStatusTip(status_tip)

        if whats_this is not None:
            action.setWhatsThis(whats_this)

        if add_to_toolbar:
            # Adds plugin icon to Plugins toolbar
            self.iface.addToolBarIcon(action)

        if add_to_menu:
            self.iface.addPluginToMenu(
                self.menu,
                action)

        self.actions.append(action)

        return action

    def initGui(self):
        """Create the menu entries and toolbar icons inside the QGIS GUI."""

        icon_path = ':/plugins/mon_super_calculateur/icon.png'
        self.add_action(
            icon_path,
            text=self.tr(u'Calculer'),
            callback=self.run,
            parent=self.iface.mainWindow())

        # will be set False in run()
        self.first_start = True


    def unload(self):
        for action in self.actions:
            self.iface.removePluginMenu(
                self.tr(u'&Mon Super Calculateur'),
            action)
            self.iface.removeToolBarIcon(action)


    def run(self):
        if self.first_start == True:
            self.first_start = False
            self.dlg = MonSuperCalculateurDialog()

        # show the dialog
        self.dlg.show()
        # Run the dialog event loop
        result = self.dlg.exec_()
        # See if OK was pressed
        if result:
            pass
```

The value of 'locale' variable is 'en'.

** **UPDATE** **

In the main python file, there is a code line saying that the 'locale_path' variable takes as input the folder 'i18n' and the file "MonSuperCalculateur_{}.qm'.format(locale)". However, in my folder 'i18n', I named my files "mon_super_calculateur_{}.qm".
So I changed "MonSuperCalculateur_{}.qm'.format(locale)" to "mon_super_calculateur_{}.qm'.format(locale)" and now it works... partially.

All my labels but two are translated correctly. Both thoses labels concern one button in tab1 and tab2.
The same phenomenon happens with english and spanish.

I checked in QtLinguist, I believe I set it correctly, even though there is a '#' appearing on the button :
[image: QtLinguist parameters]

What could be the problem with this label ?

Comment: Can you show some frames of your code with definition and call of translation (usually it's tr() function)

Comment: @RainForest I added the whole python file, just in case. Tell me if you need to see this other class files. Thank you for taking the time to answer !

Comment: What is the value of "locale" variable runtime?

Comment: If you mean the "locale" variable from "locale = QSettings().value('locale/userLocale')[0:2]", the value is "en" (and yet the labels are written in french)

Comment: Wait a minute, I see right below that code line that locale_path takes folder i18n and "MonSuperCalculateur_{}.qm'.format(locale)"... but in my folder I named my files "mon_super_calculateur_{}.qm" ! Maybe that is the problem. I will test that and come back to give the result.